# How to insert nested params into main params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am building a Backbone/Marionette web app with Rails 5 as backend. I am sending form data with nested attributes. Unfortunately these nested attributes are added outside of the :goal parameters. How can I insert them into the main (:goal) params before save? Otherwise they are ignored and not inserted into the database.

These are my params sent to server:

```
{"id"=>"7", "title"=>"ReBook", "gtype"=>"personal", "starts_at"=>"2017-03-03", "ends_at"=>"2017-10-03", "status"=>"completed", "user_id"=>1, "user_name"=>"Mike", "likes"=>0, "starts_at_formatted"=>"2017-03-03", "ends_at_formatted"=>"2017-10-03", "goalresults_attributes"=>{"description"=>"rrr", "progress"=>"333"}, "goal"=>{"id"=>"7", "user_id"=>1, "title"=>"Rebook", "gtype"=>"personal", "starts_at"=>"2017-03-03", "ends_at"=>"2017-10-03", "status"=>"completed"}}
```

Comment: I assume you're using strong params. Could you post the relevant code from your controller?

Answer (score 0):

```
params['goal']['user_name'] = params['user_name']
params['goal']['likes'] = params['likes']
params['goal']['starts_at_formatted'] = params['starts_at_formatted']
params['goal']['goalresults_attributes'] = params['goalresults_attributes']
params['goal']['progress'] = params['progress']
```

Put this in before you do do `update_attributes`

It's very dirty/ugly. But it will get the job done

Comment: I wouldn't do this. He should be using strong parameters.

Comment: @mmichael You still can use strong parameters. As long as you do this before the `permit` and `require`. Just shuffles things around

Comment: If he structures his strong params properly (and is using `accepts_nested_attributes_for`), he shouldn't need to combine them manually like that.

Comment: @mmichael I agree that that is the way to go. Except the params the come form the form are not properly nested. So strong params and accepts_nested_attributes_for will do nothing at all. The proper fix would be modifying the form or nesting them manually on the server side. THEN you can run them through all the proper channels

Comment: agreed, and until he edits his question with the code we won't be able to help :|